# How to write multiple lines to file in C++ without losing previous lines

Tags: c++

I need to write multiple lines in a txt and binary file and I created a function (I'll attach it below) that's supposed to write a few array items into the file. The problem is, I used fprintf while I open and close the file in the same function and so every time my for (because it's an array) calls the function, it overwrites the file. I'm thinking of opening the file and closing it before and after the for, respectively. Is there a more elegant way of doing what I'm after? Currently I'm using [File I/O](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm) for consulting purposes and it only mentions fprintf.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct numarComplex {
    int parteReala = 0;
    int parteFractionara = 0;
}numere[5];

void printareNumar (struct numarComplex numar) {
    printf("Numarul este: %d.%d\n", numar.parteReala, numar.parteFractionara);
    printf("\n");
}

void citireNumar (struct numarComplex *numar) {
    printf ("Introduceti partea reala: ");
    scanf("%d", &numar -> parteReala);
    printf ("Introduceti partea fractionara: ");
    scanf("%d", &numar -> parteFractionara);
}

void scriereNumarTxt (struct numarComplex numar) {
    // am decis ca la alegerea data sa se scrie in fisier .txt, sa se utilizeze numerele introduse de la tastatura in 1, pentru comoditate
    FILE *nrTxt;
    nrTxt = fopen("./numarcomplex.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(nrTxt, "%d.%d\n", numar.parteReala, numar.parteFractionara);
    fclose(nrTxt);
}

int main()
{
    int optiune;
    do {
        printf("Meniu: \n");
        printf("1. Citire de la tastatura: \n");
        printf("2. Afisare la ecran: \n");
        printf("3. Citire din fisier text: \n");
        printf("4. Scriere in fisier text: \n");
        printf("5. Citire din fisier binar: \n");
        printf("6. Scriere in fisier binar: \n");
        printf("7. Iesire: ");
        scanf("%d", &optiune);
        switch (optiune) {
        case 1: {for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                citireNumar(&numere[i]);
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            printf("Tabloul de structuri: \n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                printareNumar(numere[i]);
            }
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                scriereNumarTxt(numere[i]);
            } break;
        }
        }
    } while (optiune != 7);

}
```

Comment: Have you checked [fopen docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) prior to asking this question?

Comment: Please provide an example stripped from ballast.

Comment: What does the `fopen` manual say `"w+"` means? What other modes can you use that will work better for the intended behaviour? Even better, just open the file once outside the function and pass in the `FILE` pointer to the function.

Comment: @pqans what do you mean by ballast? I was previously warned to insert the entire program.

Comment: *"I know there's both C and C++ in my code, I explained why in my previous topic"* - there is not a single reason for both tags to be used here at the same time. *"I was previously warned to insert the entire program"* - you should provide [mcve], not just dump all your code here.

Comment: @Liviu Ganea: Have you read the [mre] section?

Comment: You don't need to show the entire program but only a complete program. Complete means it is compilable and contains everything to reproduce the issue. No need for menus and other stuff.

Comment: I don't understand your "PS". Your code does not compile with a C compiler, this question is not about why the code doesn't compile with a C compiler either. So why use the C tag? It just distracts folk who listen on the C tag.

Comment: This will not compile on a C compiler so it shouldn't have the C tag. Please check C and C++ [tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) for tag usage guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```c
#include <fstream>

int main() {  
  std::ofstream outfile;

  outfile.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::app); // append instead of overwrite
  outfile << "Data"; 
  return 0;
}
```

Above method will append the file

Comment: `outfile.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::app)` is so much more readable than `fopen("test.txt", "a")` :)